# Is the second partial derivative test inconclusive?

Tags: partial-derivative, 3d, maxima-minima

Is the second partial derivative test, $f_{xx}=0$, inconclusive? If yes, I am confused as to why my textbook says this function:

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+x^2y+4$$

Has a minimum point at $(0,0)$. When I use the test, It ends up as $D=4>0$ and $f_{xx}=0$, so how I am supposed to get to the conclusion it is a minimum point?

Comment: Well, $f_{xx}(x,y)=2+2y$, so $f_{xx}(0,0)=2>0$ and $(0,0)$ is a local minimum point. Perhaps check your calculations again? Also note that if $D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}>0$ and the mixed partial derivatives are continuous, so $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$, then $f_{xx}=0$ cannot happen.

Comment: Please format your question. The key basic point is to enclose math between \$ \$.

Comment: Tried to edit it. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You have only been using this site for a couple of weeks, but fairly soon people will just start closing and ignoring your questions unless you make the effort to format them.

Comment: @almagest Yes, that was what I meant, thank you a lot. Actually, this was my first question on stack math, So I didn't knew how to write Equations. Will do it next time.

Comment: @NewbieRose This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is great for the more tricky stuff. MSE can be intimidating until one has found one's feet. But most people try to be helpful most of the time!

Comment: Close voters. Please note that (1) this was the OP's first question; (2) the question has been clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this was your first question. So well done! MSE can be intimidating at first.

Well $f_{xx}=2+2y$, so $f_{xx}(0,0)=2>0$.

There is quite a reasonable [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) article on the test.

You probably made an error calculating $f_{xx}$. I am afraid you were not helped by the initial edit carried out for you on the question. But then your original question was a little confusing. Good formatting really helps!

Incidentally, this function also illustrates the dangers of math software. Here is a plot from Mathematica:

[image]

At a quick glance it looks as though it might be a saddle point. But if you look closely, maybe not. But if you do a 2D plot along any line through the origin, it has a minimum at the origin (not that that is conclusive).

If you need further help please comment below this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When unsure, convert the function to polar coordinates around the point $(x_0, y_0)$ being examined, using
$$\begin{cases}
x = x_0 + r \cos\theta \\
y = y_0 + r \sin\theta \\
\end{cases}$$
In this case, around $(0, 0)$,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(r, \theta) & = & (r \cos \theta)^2 + (r \sin \theta)^2 + (r \cos \theta)^2 (r \sin \theta) + 4 \\
~ & = & r^2 + r^3 (\cos\theta)^2 (\sin\theta) + 4
\end{array}$$

Next, find the minimum and maximum contribution from the angular component $\theta$.  In this case,
$$-\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}} \le (\cos\theta)^2 (\sin\theta) \le \frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$
i.e. $-0.3849 \le (\cos\theta)^2(\sin\theta) \le +0.3849$.
(These correspond to the directions $\theta$ where the surface changes most rapidly.)

Thus, the entire surface (around point $(0,0)$) is bounded between $f_{min}$ and $f_{max}$,
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{min}(r) = r^2 - \frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}} r^3 + 4 \\
f_{max}(r) = r^2 + \frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}} r^3 + 4 \\
\end{aligned}$$

If you draw $f_{min}(r)$ and $f_{max}(r)$ for $r \ge 0$, you'll see they both curve upwards from 4!
This means that there indeed is a small dip or valley at $(0,0)$.

You can clearly see this if you plot the original function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + x^2 y + 4$ close to origin, say $(-1,-1)-(+1,+1)$.

In fact, plotting region $(-1,-1)-(+1,+1)$, and comparing it to first $(-2,-2)-(+2,+2)$ and then to $(-10,-10)-(+10,+10)$ is an excellent example of how important it is to look at the problem at different scales to see which one makes most intuitive sense.  You can use Gnuplot for interactive examination,

```
set isosamples 20 ; set hidden3d
set xrange [-1:+1] ; set yrange [-1:+1] ; splot x*x+y*y+x*x*y+4 notitle w surface
```

or e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*x%2By*y%2Bx*x*y%2B4) online.